# When I set some items to view.invisible in getView(), others don't appear

Tags: java, android, listview, imageview, getview

VisiIn my custom adapter getView method, I have a switch case for different types of layout cells. I refer to one layout xml for these cells and show/hide certain elements by setVisibility(View....) In my first cell, "StreamLayout," all I want to show is one imageView, "Boombox". I set this image view as invisible in all the other layouts, but when I do this, it won't show up in the first one. I will provide my getView method and my layout xml:

getView:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_cell, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



         switch (type) {

                case STREAM_LAYOUT:

                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_cell, null);

                    ImageView boombox = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.boombox).setVisibility(View.Visible);




                    convertView.findViewById(R.id.cell_image).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        convertView.findViewById(R.id.divider).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        convertView.findViewById(R.id.song).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        convertView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_layout).setVisibility(View.GONE);


                    convertView.setTag(holder);


                case TALKSET_LAYOUT:
                    convertView.findViewById(R.id.boombox).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    convertView.findViewById(R.id.cell_image).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    convertView.findViewById(R.id.divider).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    convertView.findViewById(R.id.playcut).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    holder.talkset = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.talk_break_text);
                    holder.talkset.setText("TALKSET");

                    holder.talkset_icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.talk_break_image);
                    holder.talkset_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.temp_talkset);

                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                    break;

                case BREAKPOINT_LAYOUT:

                    convertView.findViewById(R.id.boombox).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    convertView.findViewById(R.id.cell_image).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    convertView.findViewById(R.id.divider).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist).setVisibility(View.GONE);



                       //convertView.findViewById(R.id.boombox).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                long l = Long.parseLong(oslist.get(position).get("hour"));

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(l);
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(l * 1000);

                int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);

                holder.song.setText("Breakpoint: "+hour+":00");

                    holder.breakpoint = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.talk_break_text);
                    holder.breakpoint.setText("BREAKPOINT");

                    holder.breakpoint_icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.talk_break_image);
                    holder.breakpoint_icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.temp_talkset);

                    convertView.setTag(holder);


                    break;

                case PLAYCUT_LAYOUT: //Playcut


                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_cell, null);

                    convertView.findViewById(R.id.boombox).setVisibility(View.GONE);


                    holder.cell_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cell_image);

                    try {
                        if(oslist.get(position).get("albumArtUrl")!=null) {
                            Picasso
                                    .with(context)
                                    .load(oslist.get(position).get("albumArtUrl"))
                                    .placeholder(R.drawable.no_album_art)
                                    .error(R.drawable.no_album_art).into(holder.cell_image);
                        }else{
                            Picasso
                                    .with(context)
                                    .load(oslist.get(position).get("artistArtUrl"))
                                    .placeholder(R.drawable.no_album_art)
                                    .error(R.drawable.no_album_art).into(holder.cell_image);
                        }

                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        holder.cell_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_album_art);
                    }

                    holder.song = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.song);
                    holder.artist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist);

                    holder.song.setText(oslist.get(position).get("songTitle"));
                    holder.artist.setText(oslist.get(position).get("artistName"));

                    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            updateView(position);
                        }
                    });

                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                    break;
                case NULL_LAYOUT:

                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                    break;

            }

        return convertView;

    }
```

MY XML

```
   <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/boombox"
        android:id="@+id/boombox"
        />

    <!-- Versatile image view storage for either boombox, no album art image, or album art -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cell_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />

    <!-- Divider between image and data -->

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

   <!-- Layout for bottom half of playcut cells -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_below="@id/divider">

        <!-- Data for Song and Artist -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/playcut">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/song"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
             />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/artist"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/song"
                android:gravity="center"
             />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Talkset and breakpoint cell data -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/talk_break"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/talk_break_image"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/talk_break_text"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/talk_break_image"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Playcut Cell, clicked, displaying Facebook, Twitter, heart, and search icons -->

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3,4"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/table">

            <TableRow>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/twitter_icon"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/facebook_icon"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/unclicked_heart_icon"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/search_icon"/>

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

     </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm really confused about this example, I see you setting everything to `View.GONE`, why?

Comment: Sorry sorry, i changed it

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is because you're using a `ViewHolder` which will maintain a reference to each UI element for all adapter items.

Because of this, if an element is set to `View.GONE` in the first iteration and isn't touched again, it will remain in that state, regardless of how it is defined in the XML.

To work around this, you should always explicitly set the visibility of that element in `getView()` depending on which layout you are using, because if it is anything but the first iteration you will be referencing the ViewHolder and the state it is in, not the view inflated by the XML file.

Comment: I set the R.id.boombox to view.Visible and nothing changed

Comment: you should inflate your views **only** when you get a null *convertView*.

Comment: @TeddyWilson in all of your examples you're setting it to `View.GONE` as far as I can see. Which layouts do you expect it to be visible for?

Comment: @McAdam331sorry, it is supposed to work in stream_layout, though even when it says visible, it doesn't work

Comment: also, your switch is missing `break`

Comment: ^Also, as blackbelt pointed out, you shouldn't inflate the layout each time in StreamLayout, it defeats the purpose of having a viewHolder.

Comment: yep, i'm dumb. just realized it was the switch. thanks everyone